# C - Reading and iterating through data from file to calculate totals

Tags: c, file, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a program that reads in data from a file called grad.dat. Each record (i.e. each line) in the data file gives statistics for a given country, year, degree, and gender, etc. The records are formatted as follows:

Note: there are only 3 different types of degrees - L6, L7, and L8

General format of grad.dat:

```
AUS Australia F L6 2010 1276
AUS Australia M L6 2010 5779
AUS Australia F L6 2011 1255
AUS Australia M L6 2011 5739
BEL Belgium F L6 2017 157
BEL Belgium M L6 2017 1665
BEL Belgium F L7 2010 61
BEL Belgium F L8 2016 0
BEL Belgium F L8 2017 1
BEL Belgium M L8 2017 13
BRA Brazil F L6 2010 7187
BRA Brazil M L6 2010 32173
BRA Brazil F L6 2011 6240
BRA Brazil M L6 2011 30527
BRA Brazil M L6 2014 30156
BRA Brazil M L6 2016 32443
CAN Canada F L6 2010 561
CAN Canada F L6 2012 599
CAN Canada M L6 2012 3018
```

I'm trying to use this data to generate a series of reports. I'm stuck on the first report where I have to include:

The graduate percentage for each country, by degree, for all years and all genders

a. each country will be a row, and there will be a column for each type of degree, plus one column for
all degrees combined

b. each cell will show the proportion of graduates in that specific country, for that specific degree,
compared to the total graduates in all countries combined, for that degree

So generally, I want the first report to be printed like:

```
Country          L6         L7        L8       Total
----------------------------------------------------
Country#1         %          %         %       

Country#2         .....                         

Country#3
```

My program compiles. I'm required to store the graduate data in a linked list which I think I did correctly, but I'm having trouble with figuring out how to find the total number of graduates for all degrees in a specific country, as well as the total graduates in all countries combined, for that degree. My attempt at this is in report.c and I think I have the right idea of declaring variables for each degree (L6, L7, L8) and then adding the number of grads to the variable if the record's degree in the file matches the variable. I also think I have the right idea of finding the total number of graduates in a specific country by doing totalAllDegreesForCountry = L6+L7+L8.

I'm running into issues where it keeps printing the same country multiple times as the country has multiple records in the file. I'm trying to figure out how to print each country only once. My program also seems to print all the records and then seg fault at the very end and I'm not sure why.

I think the stats may be off too as it's printing values 1.00 and 0.00.

I would really appreciate some help with this or a push in the right direction in getting my first report to print correctly.

defs.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR 32

typedef struct {
  char code[MAX_STR];
  char country[MAX_STR];
  char gender[MAX_STR];
  char degree[MAX_STR];
  int year;
  int numberOfGrads;
} DataType;

typedef struct Node {
  DataType *data;
  struct Node *next;
} NodeType;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    NodeType *head;
    NodeType *tail;
} ListType;
void initData(DataType**, char*, char*, char*, char*, int, int);
void printData(const DataType*);
void addDataToList(ListType *list, DataType *m);
void printList(ListType*);  
void reportOne(ListType*);
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "defs.h"   
int main()
{
  FILE *infile;  
  DataType *data;
  ListType *list ;
  char code[MAX_STR];
  char country[MAX_STR];
  char gender[MAX_STR];
  char degree[MAX_STR];
  int year;
  int numberOfGrads;
  char input[MAX_STR];

  list->size = 0;
  list->head = NULL;
  list->tail = NULL;

  infile = fopen("grad.dat", "r");
  if (!infile) {
    printf("Error: could not open file\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  
  while (1) {
    fscanf(infile, "%s %s %s %s %d %d ", code, country, gender, degree, &year,  &numberOfGrads);
    initData(&data, code, country, gender, degree, year, numberOfGrads);
    addDataToList(list, data);
    if (feof(infile))
      break;
  }
  fclose(infile);

  while (1){
     printf(" 0. Quit \n");
     printf(" 1 = Top 5 and bottom 5 countries of female graduates \n");

    printf("Enter a selection: ");
    scanf("%s", input);  

    if(strcmp(input, "1")==0){
        reportOne(list);
    }else if(strcmp(input, "0")==0){
      break;
    }
  }
}

void initData(DataType **r, char *co, char *c, char *g, char *d, int y, int n){
    *r = malloc(sizeof(DataType));
    strcpy((*r)->code, co);
    strcpy((*r)->country, c);
    strcpy((*r)->gender, g);
    strcpy((*r)->degree, d);
    (*r)->year = y;
    (*r)->numberOfGrads = n;
}

void printData(const DataType *data){
    printf("%s %s %s %s %d %d\n", data->code, data->country, data->gender, data->degree, data->year, data->numberOfGrads);
}

void addDataToList(ListType *list, DataType *m){
  NodeType *currNode;
  NodeType *prevNode;
  NodeType *newNode;

  prevNode=NULL;

  int currPos = 0;
  currNode = list->head;


  while (currNode != NULL) {
    prevNode = currNode;
    currNode = currNode->next;
  }

  newNode = malloc(sizeof(NodeType));
  newNode->data = m;
  newNode->prev = NULL;
  newNode->next = NULL;

  if (prevNode == NULL)
    list->head = newNode;
  else
    prevNode->next = newNode;

  if (currNode == NULL)
    list->tail = newNode;


  newNode->next = currNode;
  newNode->prev = prevNode;

  if (currNode != NULL)
    currNode->prev = newNode;
  list->size++;
  }

}

void printList(ListType* list){
    NodeType *currNode = list->head;
    while(currNode != NULL){
        printData(currNode->data);
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }
}
```

reports.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "defs.h"

void reportOne(ListType* list){
  NodeType *currNode = list->head;
 
  float L6 = 0;
  float L7 = 0;
  float L8 = 0;
  
  float totalGradsCountry = 0; //specific country
  float totalGradsAll = 0; //all degrees all countries
  
  printf("%15s %10s %10s %10s %10s \n", "Country", "L6","L7","L8", "Total");
  printf("-------------------------------------------------------- \n");

  while (currNode != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(currNode->data->country, currNode->next->data->country) == 0){
            if(strcmp(currNode->data->degree, "L6")==0){ 
                L6 += currNode->data->numberOfGrads;
            }else if(strcmp(currNode->data->degree,"L7")==0){
                L7 += currNode->data->numberOfGrads;
            }else if(strcmp(currNode->data->degree,"L8")==0){
                L8 += currNode->data->numberOfGrads;
            }
            totalGradsCountry = L6 + L7 + L8;
            totalGradsAll += totalGradsCountry;
      printf("%-15s %6.2f %6.2f %6.2f %7.2f \n", currNode->data->country, L6/totalGradsCountry, L7/totalGradsCountry, L8/totalGradsCountry, totalGradsCountry/totalGradsAll);
        }
    currNode = currNode->next;
  }
}
```

I have attached 2 pictures below of my output to show what I mean with the issues I'm facing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Explain `void addDataToList(NodeType**, DataType*);` in `defs.h` and `void addDataToList (ListType * list, DataType * m)` in `main.c`? (note the parameter type difference) You should include *header-guards* in `defs.h` to prevent multiple inclusion. You can delete the headers from `defs.h`

Comment: Ah sorry, that was an old version I forgot to edit. I have updated the code with the correct parameters in defs.h

Comment: Also `list->size = 0;` where `list` is an uninitialized pointer -- likely to SegFault when dereferenced. `main.c` ~ line 19. You may as well just declare `ListType list;` (or allocate for it -- your choice)

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, your primary problem is derefencing a `NULL` in `reports.c` at:

```
    while (currNode != NULL) {
        if (strcmp (currNode->data->country, currNode->next->data->country) ==
```

on your last node, the `node->next` pointer is `NULL` yet you attempt to access `currNode->next->...` Boom! SegFault!

You simply need to use `currNode->next` in your conditional, e.g.

```
    while (currNode->next != NULL) {
        if (strcmp (currNode->data->country, currNode->next->data->country) ==
```

Next, the link [Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) explains why your read loop will cause problems. Always control your read-loop with the **return** of the input function, e.g.

```
    while (fscanf (infile, "%s %s %s %s %d %d ", code, country, gender, degree,
                &year, &numberOfGrads) == 6) {
        if (!(data = initData (code, country, gender, degree, year, numberOfGrads)))
            return 1;
        addDataToList (list, data);
    }
```

If you notice, the declaration for `initData` has changed. You have no valid way to indicate success or failure of `mailloc` in `initData` before you blindly start using `*r`. Instead in any function that allocates memory, takes user input, etc. (*any function that is critical to the continued operation of your code*), you need to choose a meaningful return type that you can use to indicate success/failure of your function.

There is no need to pass the address of the pointer `data` as a parameter. Instead, declare `r` local to your function and then return `NULL` on failure or an allocated block for assignment back in the caller. You can change the prototype to:

```
DataType *initData (char*, char*, char*, char*, int, int);
```

and then simply have the function return `NULL` on failure or `r` on success, e.g.

```
DataType *initData (char *co, char *c, char *g, char *d, int y, int n)
{
    DataType *r = malloc (sizeof (DataType));
    if (!r) {
        perror ("malloc-initData");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy (r->code, co);
    strcpy (r->country, c);
    strcpy (r->gender, g);
    strcpy (r->degree, d);
    r->year = y;
    r->numberOfGrads = n;
    
    return r;
}
```

Lastly, your `addDataToList()` function suffers from the same `void` type and no ability to indicate success/failure of `malloc()` (I'll let you rewrite this one). In the mean time, you must protect against an out-of-memory error. You can further vastly shorten how you add a node to your list. Doing both, and using the `tail` pointer for what a `tail` pointer is supposed to be used for, you could do:

```
void addDataToList (ListType * list, DataType * m)
{
    NodeType *newNode = malloc (sizeof (NodeType));
    if (!newNode) {
        perror ("malloc-newNode");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    newNode->data = m;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    
    if (!list->head)
        list->head = list->tail = newNode;
    else {
        newNode->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail->next = newNode;
        list->tail = newNode;
    }

    list->size++;
}
```

**Use Header-Guards To Prevent Multiple Inclusions of the Header**

When writing a header file, you only want it included in the compilation once (it can cause problems when included multiple times, e.g. redefinition of `X`, etc..) To ensure the header is only included once, you wrap the content in a

```
#infdef SOME_HEADER_LABEL_H
#define SOME_HEADER_LABEL_H  1
...
your header content
...
#endif
```

That way on first inclusion, the compiler checks if `SOME_HEADER_LABEL_H` is defined, and if it isn't, it defines it with `#define SOME_HEADER_LABEL_H  1` so that the next time it is included, it will simply skip the content. (the `1` isn't strictly necessary -- it can be omitted, but if you are going to define a constant, you may as well give it a value). For your header that could be:

```
#ifndef DEFS_H
#define DEFS_H 1

#define MAX_STR 32

typedef struct {
    char code[MAX_STR];
    char country[MAX_STR];
    char gender[MAX_STR];
    char degree[MAX_STR];
    int year;
    int numberOfGrads;
} DataType;

typedef struct Node {
    DataType *data;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
} NodeType;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    NodeType *head;
    NodeType *tail;
} ListType;

// void initData(DataType**, char*, char*, char*, char*, int, int);
DataType *initData (char*, char*, char*, char*, int, int);
void printData(const DataType*);
void addDataToList (ListType*, DataType*);
void reportOne(ListType*);

#endif
```

**No Need To Allocate For `data` In `main()`**

On second look, there is no need to allocated for `DataType *data;` in `main()` at all. It is a temporary, so just declare it with *automatic storage* type and reuse it for all input -- but you will need to allocate for `newNode->data` in `addDataToList` and `memcpy` rather than assign `m`. So either way is fine. (that code is shown commented in the update related to the report output shown in the edit below)

**Avoid MagicNumbers and Hardcoded Filenames**

In your code you hardcode `"grad.dat"` as the filename to read. That means you must recompile your code every time you want to read from another file. Instead, pass the filename to read as an argument to your program using `int main (int argc, char **argv)` -- that's what the parameters to `main()` are for. You can use a simple ternary to read from the filename given as an argument, or if no argument is given, read from `"grad.dat"` by default. That's fine, but define a constant for the filename, e.g.

```
#define DATAFILE "grad.dat"
...
    /* do not hardcode filenames, you can use it as a default */
    infile = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : DATAFILE, "r");
    if (!infile) {  /* good job validating fopen */
        printf ("Error: could not open file\n");
        exit (1);
    }
```

---

**Making `reportOne()` Summarize by Country**

This took a bit more thinking to arrive at. There are several ways to go about it. You either use a slightly more complicated data structure to hold the summary data for each country along with the `totalGradsCountry` value, or you store only the summary of the country data, and then must traverse your list twice in `reportOne()`, once to sum `totalGradsCountry`, and then again to output the results using your `totalGradsCountry`.

Basically to capture the information while traversing the list a single time takes building an array of the unique countries along with the sums of `L6`, `L7`, and `L8` captured along with the `country` (name) and optionally `code` (makes for a shorter `strcmp` to determine the country in the node). So you could use something like:

```
#define NSUM 2                  /* initial no. of countrytype to allocate */

typedef struct {                /* struct to hold summary of country data */
    char  code[MAX_STR],
          country[MAX_STR];
    double  L6, 
            L7,
            L8;
} countrytype;

typedef struct {                /* struct to hold array of countries and totalgrads */
    countrytype *countries;
    double totalGradsAll;
} totaltype;
```

Then it is a matter of traversing your full list, and for each unique country, allocate storage for a `countrytype` and on the first node for that country, copy the `code` and `country` information, and for all remaining entries for that country add to the `L6`, `L7`, and `L8` values and to the `totalGradsAll` sum. When allocating (and reallocating) for the `countrytype`, zeroing the memory allows you to check if `code` is the empty-string to know if you have the first-occurrence of that country.

The `reportOne()` function becomes:

```
void reportOne (ListType *list)
{
    size_t used = 0, avail = NSUM;      /* number used, number allocated */
    totaltype total = { .countries = calloc (avail, sizeof(countrytype)) };
    NodeType *node = list->head;
    
    if (!total.countries) {             /* validate initial allocation */
        perror ("calloc-.countries");
        return;
    }
    
    while (node) {  /* loop over each node in list */
        /* check if country code exists in summary list of countries */
        size_t ndx = codeexists (total.countries, node->data->code, &used);
        
        if (used == avail)  /* check if realloc needed */
            total.countries = addcountry (total.countries, &avail);
        
        addtosum (&total, ndx, node->data);     /* add current node info to summary */
        
        node = node->next;      /* advance to next node */
    }
    
    puts (  "\nCountry            L6        L7        L8        Total\n"
            "-------------------------------------------------------");
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < used; i++) {     /* loop over countries in summary */
        /* sum L6 + L7 + L8 for country */
        double totalGradsCountry =  total.countries[i].L6 + total.countries[i].L7 + 
                                    total.countries[i].L8;
        /* output results */
        printf ("%-15s %6.2f    %6.2f    %6.2f    %7.2f\n",
                total.countries[i].country,
                total.countries[i].L6 / totalGradsCountry,
                total.countries[i].L7 / totalGradsCountry,
                total.countries[i].L8 / totalGradsCountry,
                totalGradsCountry / total.totalGradsAll);
    }
    
    free (total.countries);     /* free all memory allocated for summary */ 
}
```

Now you see several helper-functions that by putting them in functions help keep your `reportOne` logic readable. The helpers are `codeexists()` (e.g. does this country code already exist in the block of `countrytype`) Having it return the `index` to the country in the allocated block of `countrytype` allows you to simply update the `L6`, `L7`, and `L8` at that index. If the index doesn't exist, it is a new country that you add to your `used` count to keep track of when a reallocation is needed. It is a simple function:

```
/* returns index of country matching code or next available index,
 * incrementing the value at n (used) for each new index returned.
 */
size_t codeexists (const countrytype *c, const char *code, size_t *n)
{
    size_t i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)                    /* loop over countries */
        if (strcmp (c[i].code, code) == 0)      /* if codes match, break to return index */
            break;
    
    if (i == *n)        /* if code not found in countries */
        *n += 1;        /* new country found, increment n (used) */
    
    return i;           /* return index */
}
```

The next helper is `addcountry()` which when your `used == avail` (used blocks for countries equals the number allocated), a reallocation is needed and that is what `addcountry()` does, returing a pointer to the newly reallocated block for assignment (or exiting if an error occurs), e.g.

```
/* reallocate countries when used == available,
 * new memory is zeroed for 1st char check in addtosum,
 * program exits on memory failure.
 */
countrytype *addcountry (countrytype *c, size_t *avail)
{
    /* always realloc using a temporary pointer */
    void *tmp = realloc (c, 2 * *avail * sizeof *c);
    if (!tmp) { /* validate reallocation */
        perror ("realloc-countrytype");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    c = tmp;                                        /* assing realloc'ed block to ptr */
    memset (c + *avail, 0, *avail * sizeof *c);     /* zero newly allocated memory */
    *avail *= 2;                                    /* update no. of countries avail */
    
    return c;       /* return pointer for assignment in caller */
}
```

The last helper is `addtosum()` which simply copies `code` and `country` names if needed and updates `L6`, `L7`, and `L8` for the given index,

```
/* add current nodes information to the country and total sums */
void addtosum (totaltype *t, size_t ndx, DataType *d)
{
    if (!*t->countries[ndx].code) {                 /* if new country, copy info */
        strcpy (t->countries[ndx].code, d->code);
        strcpy (t->countries[ndx].country, d->country);
    }
    
    switch (d->degree[1]) { /* switch on 2nd character */
        case '6':   t->countries[ndx].L6 += d->numberOfGrads; break;
        case '7':   t->countries[ndx].L7 += d->numberOfGrads; break;
        case '8':   t->countries[ndx].L8 += d->numberOfGrads; break;
        default :   fputs ("error: addtosum switch -- we shouldn't be here\n", stderr);
                    return;
    }
    t->totalGradsAll += d->numberOfGrads;  /* add to total for all */
}
```

A `switch()` is used above on the 2nd character of the `degree`, e.g. `6`, `7`, or `8` to updated to appropriate value without needing to call `strcmp()` each time.

**Putting It Altogether**

Those are the changes needed. So your `defs.h` becomes:

```
#ifndef DEFS_H
#define DEFS_H 1

#define MAX_STR 32

typedef struct {
    char code[MAX_STR];
    char country[MAX_STR];
    char gender[MAX_STR];
    char degree[MAX_STR];
    int year;
    int numberOfGrads;
} DataType;

typedef struct Node {
    DataType *data;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
} NodeType;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    NodeType *head;
    NodeType *tail;
} ListType;

// void initData (DataType*, char*, char*, char*, char*, int, int);
DataType *initData (char*, char*, char*, char*, int, int);
void printData (const DataType*);
void addDataToList (ListType*, DataType*);
void reportOne (ListType*);
// void reportTwo (ListType*);

#endif
```

Your `main.c` (with the code commented out showing to use `data` with automatic storage duration) becaomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "defs.h"

#define DATAFILE "grad.dat"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *infile;
    DataType *data;
    ListType *list = malloc (sizeof *list);
    char code[MAX_STR];
    char country[MAX_STR];
    char gender[MAX_STR];
    char degree[MAX_STR];
    int year;
    int numberOfGrads;
    char input[MAX_STR];
    
    if (!list) {    /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-list");
        return 1;
    }
    
    list->size = 0;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    
    /* do not hardcode filenames, you can use it as a default */
    infile = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : DATAFILE, "r");
    if (!infile) {  /* good job validating fopen */
        printf ("Error: could not open file\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    
    /* always control read-loop with return of the input function itself */
    while (fscanf (infile, "%s %s %s %s %d %d ", code, country, gender, degree,
                &year, &numberOfGrads) == 6) {
        if (!(data = initData (code, country, gender, degree, year, numberOfGrads)))
            return 1;
        addDataToList (list, data);
    }
    fclose (infile);
    
    while (1) {
        fputs ( "\n 0. Quit \n"
                " 1 = Top 5 and bottom 5 countries of female graduates\n"
                "Enter a selection: ", stdout);
        if (scanf ("%s", input) != 1) {
            puts ("(user canceled input)");
            return 1;
        }

        if (strcmp (input, "1") == 0) {
            reportOne (list);
        }
        else if (strcmp (input, "0") == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

DataType *initData (char *co, char *c, char *g, char *d, int y, int n)
{
    DataType *r = malloc (sizeof (DataType));
    if (!r) {
        perror ("malloc-initData");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy (r->code, co);
    strcpy (r->country, c);
    strcpy (r->gender, g);
    strcpy (r->degree, d);
    r->year = y;
    r->numberOfGrads = n;
    
    return r;
}

/* initData for use of data with automatic storage in main */
// void initData (DataType *r, char *co, char *c, char *g, char *d, int y, int n)
// {
//     strcpy (r->code, co);
//     strcpy (r->country, c);
//     strcpy (r->gender, g);
//     strcpy (r->degree, d);
//     r->year = y;
//     r->numberOfGrads = n;
// }

void printData (const DataType * data)
{
    printf ("%s %s %s %s %d %d\n", data->code, data->country, data->gender,
            data->degree, data->year, data->numberOfGrads);
}

void addDataToList (ListType * list, DataType * m)
{
    NodeType *newNode = malloc (sizeof (NodeType));
    if (!newNode) {
        perror ("malloc-newNode");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* allocation and copy if using data with automatic storage in main */
    // if (!(newNode->data = malloc (sizeof *newNode->data))) {
    //     perror ("malloc-newNode->data");
    //     exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    // }
    
    // memcpy (newNode->data, m, sizeof *m);
    newNode->data = m;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    
    if (!list->head)
        list->head = list->tail = newNode;
    else {
        newNode->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail->next = newNode;
        list->tail = newNode;
    }

    list->size++;
}
```

Finally the updated `reports.c` becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "defs.h"

#define NSUM 2                  /* initial no. of countrytype to allocate */

typedef struct {                /* struct to hold summary of country data */
    char  code[MAX_STR],
          country[MAX_STR];
    double  L6, 
            L7,
            L8;
} countrytype;

typedef struct {                /* struct to hold array of countries and totalgrads */
    countrytype *countries;
    double totalGradsAll;
} totaltype;

/* returns index of country matching code or next available index,
 * incrementing the value at n (used) for each new index returned.
 */
size_t codeexists (const countrytype *c, const char *code, size_t *n)
{
    size_t i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)                    /* loop over countries */
        if (strcmp (c[i].code, code) == 0)      /* if codes match, break to return index */
            break;
    
    if (i == *n)        /* if code not found in countries */
        *n += 1;        /* new country found, increment n (used) */
    
    return i;           /* return index */
}

/* reallocate countries when used == available,
 * new memory is zeroed for 1st char check in addtosum,
 * program exits on memory failure.
 */
countrytype *addcountry (countrytype *c, size_t *avail)
{
    /* always realloc using a temporary pointer */
    void *tmp = realloc (c, 2 * *avail * sizeof *c);
    if (!tmp) { /* validate reallocation */
        perror ("realloc-countrytype");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    c = tmp;                                        /* assing realloc'ed block to ptr */
    memset (c + *avail, 0, *avail * sizeof *c);     /* zero newly allocated memory */
    *avail *= 2;                                    /* update no. of countries avail */
    
    return c;       /* return pointer for assignment in caller */
}

/* add current nodes information to the country and total sums */
void addtosum (totaltype *t, size_t ndx, DataType *d)
{
    if (!*t->countries[ndx].code) {                 /* if new country, copy info */
        strcpy (t->countries[ndx].code, d->code);
        strcpy (t->countries[ndx].country, d->country);
    }
    
    switch (d->degree[1]) { /* switch on 2nd character */
        case '6':   t->countries[ndx].L6 += d->numberOfGrads; break;
        case '7':   t->countries[ndx].L7 += d->numberOfGrads; break;
        case '8':   t->countries[ndx].L8 += d->numberOfGrads; break;
        default :   fputs ("error: addtosum switch -- we shouldn't be here\n", stderr);
                    return;
    }
    t->totalGradsAll += d->numberOfGrads;  /* add to total for all */
}

void reportOne (ListType *list)
{
    size_t used = 0, avail = NSUM;      /* number used, number allocated */
    totaltype total = { .countries = calloc (avail, sizeof(countrytype)) };
    NodeType *node = list->head;
    
    if (!total.countries) {             /* validate initial allocation */
        perror ("calloc-.countries");
        return;
    }
    
    while (node) {  /* loop over each node in list */
        /* check if country code exists in summary list of countries */
        size_t ndx = codeexists (total.countries, node->data->code, &used);
        
        if (used == avail)  /* check if realloc needed */
            total.countries = addcountry (total.countries, &avail);
        
        addtosum (&total, ndx, node->data);     /* add current node info to summary */
        
        node = node->next;      /* advance to next node */
    }
    
    puts (  "\nCountry            L6        L7        L8        Total\n"
            "-------------------------------------------------------");
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < used; i++) {     /* loop over countries in summary */
        /* sum L6 + L7 + L8 for country */
        double totalGradsCountry =  total.countries[i].L6 + total.countries[i].L7 + 
                                    total.countries[i].L8;
        /* output results */
        printf ("%-15s %6.2f    %6.2f    %6.2f    %7.2f\n",
                total.countries[i].country,
                total.countries[i].L6 / totalGradsCountry,
                total.countries[i].L7 / totalGradsCountry,
                total.countries[i].L8 / totalGradsCountry,
                totalGradsCountry / total.totalGradsAll);
    }
    
    free (total.countries);     /* free all memory allocated for summary */ 
}
```

Note -- all memory used in `reportOne()` is freed before returning. You need to make sure you clean up after the remainder of your code as well.

Take your time to work through how the `countrytype` and `totaltype` structures are used to produce the final output. There is a lot there, so just *Slow Down* and take it line-by-line and follow it trough.

**Example Use/Output**

With the limited sample data provided, you would receive:

```
$ ./bin/main 

 0. Quit 
 1 = Top 5 and bottom 5 countries of female graduates
Enter a selection: 1

Country            L6        L7        L8        Total
-------------------------------------------------------
Australia         1.00      0.00      0.00       0.09
Belgium           0.96      0.03      0.01       0.01
Brazil            1.00      0.00      0.00       0.87
Canada            1.00      0.00      0.00       0.03

 0. Quit 
 1 = Top 5 and bottom 5 countries of female graduates
Enter a selection:
```

Which given the values in the sample-data looks like it is what would be expected. Confirming is left to you.

Your code should run fine with those changes. If it doesn't, drop a comment, I may have forgotten a change or two. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much, it got rid of the seg fault :) My only other issue I'm trying to figure out is how to print each country only once with their stats instead of printing the same country 100 times like in my output pictures based on the number of records associated with the country. I think my whole math logic for reportOne() is off. The values for each degree L6, L7, and L8 all add up to 100% which makes sense but some columns have L6 print 100% and other columns print 0% even though in the file there are thousands of graduates for each degree

Comment: I have another edit coming -- hold on for that one `:)`

Comment: I'll look at the print each country only once issue.